# How to check if process is still running?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the constructor:

```
if (Process.GetProcessesByName(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Elgato\GameCapture\GameCapture.exe").Length == 0)
            {
                 Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Elgato\GameCapture\GameCapture.exe");
            }
```

The problem is that even if the process running it's trying to start it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the process is just GameCapture.  It's process name not process path.